# Sublime text volatile find next

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to replicate Eclipse volatile find next functionality (I think that is what it is called).

This is where the search term for find next will automatically be set to whatever text is highlight.

In sublime text, when I hit find next, if will jump to the next occurrence of the last term searched for. If I selected over a different term, it still will search for the last term entered when I pressed ctrl+F.

In eclipse it will always set the current search term to the current highlight text at the time find next is hit. I am a pretty big fan of this functionality.

To do something similar in sublime, I have to select the text then hit ctrl+F, esc, then find next.

Is there a way to set the search at to the current highlighted text at when find next is hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar functionality exists as "Quick Find" in Sublime Text 3 (Ctrl+F3 shortcut on Windows).  It is possible to create a sublime-keymap file to remap the "Find Next" binding (F3) to this if you desire, see the documentation here: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html.  Looking at the default mapping, the sublime text "command" for this is called `find_under`.

EDIT: Sublime Text has a "Use Selection for Find" feature (Ctrl+E, command `slurp_find_string`), which affects "Find Next" (F3) and "Find Previous" (Shift+F3).  Unfortunately, Sublime Text does not allow binding one key to multiple commands, which means that it is not possible to rebind F3 to execute the `slurp_find_string` command when the selection is not empty, and then perform a `find_next` as normal.  It may be possible by creating a plugin, however.  Someone has already done something similar here which may be helpful as a starting point: https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8677

Comment: This is not the same either. Because once I unhighlight the text, the search term is not stored. So if I have three instances of "yyy", and I highlight the first one and hit quick find, it will jump to the second one, if I then edit the second one, and hit quick find again, it will not do anything because nothing is selected. In eclipse whatever text is selected when I hit find next will automatically be stored as the search term, so I can then unhighlight and search and it will still search for that term. Its the superior method, and once you use it, you will loath losing it. So super fast.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for explaining. I have updated my answer.

Comment: "Use selection to find" will at least eliminate 1 key stroke from the equation, so that is not half bad.